# Fadeout jquery not working. Deletes successfully but doesn't fade

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

Here is part of the div i'm trying to fadeOut.

```
<% @unconfirmed_sub_posts.each do |sub| %>
  <div class = "unconfirmed_post" id = "unconfirmed_sub_post_<%=sub.id%>">
   <table class = "table">
    <tr>
      <td id = "tablenoborder">
        <%= link_to 'x', sub, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-danger btn-small", remote: true %>
      </td>
```

Notice the ID i put on the div and that i added remote:true to the link_to that sends it to the destroy controller action.

In my controller here is the destroy action.

```
  def destroy
   @sub_opp.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to sub_opps_url }
    format.js
   end
 end
```

Finally, in my destroy.js.erb file:

```
$('#unconfirmed_sub_post_<%= @sub_opp.id %>').fadeOut(500);
```

The item is getting deleted but not fading out.  When i refresh the page the div is gone. Javascript console gives me this error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/sub_opps/14 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class = "unconfirmed_post" id = "unconfirmed_sub_post_14">
  <table class = "table">
    <tr>
      <td id = "tablenoborder">
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" href="/sub_opps/14" rel="nofollow">x</a>
      </td>
      <td id = "tablenoborder">
        <b>Basketball</b> at <b>depaul</b> on <b>Saturday, January 04, 2014</b>  at <b> 4:00pm</b>.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- ANY RESPONSES TO PENDING SUB POSTS -->
  <div class = "responses_to_posts">
    <h5 class = "nomargintop">Responses</h5>
        <p class = "nonheadingtext">There are no responses yet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your rendered HTML and JS instead of the server-side code?

Comment: @brad did you fix your issue with my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my javascript file was under the wrong view subfolder.  I was trying to delete a post from the user dashboard and had the js file in the user directory when really it should have been in the post subfolder.

lesson learned: make sure js file is under the view folder of the object you are modifying, not where the link stems.

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your javascript that calls the destroy? fadeOut takes a callback. Try calling code that calls the destroy on server in your callback.
Like this

```
 $('#unconfirmed_sub_post_<%= @sub_opp.id %>').fadeOut(500, function(){
    //put your code that calls the server to destroy here
 });
```

Comment: thanks - i'm sure this is it. i'm trying to research what this code would be for the callback - pretty new to ajax.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

On form submission, you will want to fadeOut() first, and then allow submission of the form in the fadeOut() callback.